# export a gif image from powerpoint to folder

Tags: vba, animated-gif, powerpoint

I have an gif inserted in my powerpoint presentation and I want to export it to a folder using vba. I was trying to use the following code to do that:

```
 For Each s In ActivePresentation.Slides
    shapeAniNum = 0
    shapeNum = s.TimeLine.MainSequence.count
    While shapeNum <> 0
       shapeAniNum = shapeAniNum + 1
       animationNum = animationNum + 1
       If InStr(s.TimeLine.MainSequence(shapeAniNum).Shape.AlternativeText, ".gif") <> 0 Or InStr(s.TimeLine.MainSequence(shapeAniNum).Shape.AlternativeText, ".GIF") <> 0 Then
                s.TimeLine.MainSequence(shapeAniNum).Shape.Export "C:\dink_template\created_files\Animage" & animationNum & ".gif", ppShapeFormatGIF
    .....
```

The this saves the file in the created_files folder and the file extension is gif but it is not animated anymore. How can I make the export process and maintain the gif animation?

Comment: PowerPoint won't export animated gifs.  Instead, you'd have to crack the file's XML and locate the gif in the media folder.